# Send SVG image content to email as HTML using boto3

Tags: python, html, svg, outlook, boto3

I want to send SVG content (without saved file) as HTML to Outlook email address.
This SVG content works fine in browser showing a circle image, however sending it via boto3.client to Outlook email results in empty mail. Why? Any suggestions appreciated.

```
import io
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

SENDER = "Name1 LastName1 <Name1.LastName1@mail.com>"
RECIPIENT = "Name2 LastName2 <Name2.LastName2@mail.com>"
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
SUBJECT = "something"

svg = """
<svg width="100" height="100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg> 
"""

BODY_HTML = f"""<html>
<body>
{svg}
</body>
</html>
            """ 

CHARSET = "UTF-8"

client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)

try:
    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_HTML
                }
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': SUBJECT
            },
        },
        Source=SENDER
    )   
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. Used `send_raw_email` and `MIMEImage`, `cid` from `MIMEImage` was used to insert image data in html body. Updated code as follows:

```
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

SENDER = "Name1 LastName1 <Name1.LastName1@mail.com>"
RECIPIENT = "Name2 LastName2 <Name2.LastName2@mail.com>"
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
SUBJECT = "something"

png_data = image_bytes()

CHARSET = "utf-8"

client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)

msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')

msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT 
msg['From'] = SENDER 
msg['To'] = RECIPIENT

img = MIMEImage(png_data, 'png')
img.add_header("Content-Type", "image/png", name="some_name.png")
img.add_header("Content-Disposition", "inline", filename="some_name.png")
img.add_header('Content-Id', 'some_cid_name')
img.add_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'base64')

BODY_HTML = '<img src="cid:some_cid_name"/>'

email_body= MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)
msg.attach(email_body)

try:
    #Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_raw_email(
        Source=SENDER,
        Destinations=[
            RECIPIENT
        ],
        RawMessage={
            'Data':msg.as_string(),
        },
    )
# Display an error if something goes wrong. 
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
```

Answer (score 2):

SVG graphics are widely supported in web browsers but not all email programs know what to do with these new images. In case of Outlook you need to export the file to any image file format like PNG or JPEG and then attach it to the mail item. Then in the message body you can refer to use using a special syntax with a `cid:` prefix. Also you need to set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property (DASL name "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F") using the `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` method and refer that attachment through the `src` attribute that matches the value of `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` set on the attachment. `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` corresponds to the `Content-ID` MIME header when the message is sent.

```
attachment = MailItem.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "YourImageId")
MailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test image <img src=""cid:YourImageId""></body></html>"
```

Comment: Outlook seems to support SVG images (you can insert such image manually in outlook client).
The whole thing is that I need to display this example image without saving to file. Btw if I would like to do it with file only one change be required in my code like `svg = """<img src="image_address/image.jpg""""`

Comment: Does Outlook convert the chosen SVG file into image behind the scene? Have you had a chance to check the message body after?

Comment: I did check it and found the way to send image object as png bytes. I used cid as you mentioned. Thanks for a hint.

Comment: Marking your own posts as answers doesn't make any sense even if you post a ready made code after figuring it out from other answers. I'd suggest marking the answer, not the code you posted.